# Is there an easy way to generate Javascript models based on POC Entity Framework entities (e.g. for ExtJs)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extjs

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC3 application and want to incorporate ExtJs primarily for charting now, but for more functionality later.  I already have a set of POCO Entities in my architecture, and would like to have them all available for the javascript-based model.  Also, I don't want to have to maintain two sets of entities.  I figure it's probably not hard to write something that will creat JSON representations of the entities, but someone must have done this already, right?  I couldn't find it in my own searching.  Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Well javascript don't have strong typing so you don't really need js code generation, JSON is enough. Why don't serialize to JSON some .NET objects that map to the ExtJS API?

Comment: I guess in VS2012 it is possible, for either way, means you have poco object and you can copy and paste as java script object or a reverse way, I don't remember exactly but it is there as IDE functionality in VS2012

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're asking, but perhaps a C# to JavaScript compiler can help you. Alternatives I know of:

- [Saltarelle](http://www.saltarelle-compiler.com) (mine)
- [Script#](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp)
- [SharpKit](http://sharpkit.net)

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting idea! I can certainly understand the motivation. A nice solution may be to generate a javascript file from your C# models using the [T4 templating engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx).

This way you could create a template that uses reflection to grab all the types defined under a certain project or namespace and iterate over them, writing out a javascript definition for each. A little more reflection to list the public property names, and whatever javascript syntax you'd like surrounding them and you're all sorted!

Answer (score 0):

You add a reference to newtonsoft.json and you do like that

```
var model = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, new IsoDateTimeConverter()));
```

Is it what you're looking for ?

Answer (score -1):

I've been looking to do something simlar for a personal project and have found [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN which would allow you to serialize your POCOs to JSON.  There is also an [article on CodeProject entitled JSON Serialization and Deserialization in ASP.NET by SummiG](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272335/JSON-Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-NET) that gives a good -- and at first glance complete -- example of creating a static helper class.

That being said, I haven't tried it myself yet and would appreciate any feedback if you do go that route.

Comment: [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) is much faster. This is also not what the OP asked for...

Comment: I was hoping to avoid rolling my own solution.  Maybe I've found that open source project I've been meaning to start up!

Comment: @DotNetDan Well, it is pretty easy to set it up. Just use T4. I've run all my project with that. I generate my models from the EntityFramework XML file using a T4. In case of plain classes it will be a bit harder but I guess still pretty easy enough.